# zImage install on Raspberry PI 2

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, installation, raspberry-pi

I have precompiled Android Kernel and modified it. After builduing I got an zImage. The Question is how can I install and boot the zImage on my raspberry pi 2?

I'm using a SD-card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RPi won't load a normal zImage. You will need to use a tool called `imagetool-uncompressed.py` available in the [Raspberry PI Tools repo](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) to convert the zImage into the format used by the Raspberry PI.

After doing that, you can copy the `kernel.img` file into `/boot` on the SD card.

There is a reasonably complete tutorial on compiling and installing your own kernel [here](http://elinux.org/index.php?title=Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation&redirect=no) and another [here](http://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/raspberry/buildkernel/). I recommend you read these if you have not already, because there are a lot of other aspects to consider.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I did run the imagetool-uncompressed.py and it created 2 files for me. But the questions is that I have an empty SD-card. What do I need to have in the SD-card?

Comment: @Arif that's a much bigger question. You need much more than a kernel to have a functional system. I recommend starting with an existing working image such as raspbian or pidora, then put your own kernel in place.